# Cases with Same Subject line added with a Prefix as :RE is not getting identified as a duplicate case

Tags: trigger, case

Cases with Same Subject line  added with a Prefix as :RE is not getting identified as a duplicate case and getting it closed by adding its case comment to the Existing case which is Open.

The trigger gets fired when the cases are with the same subject line and get closed ,but my users are creating a case (say first case) and while creating the second case ,their are resending it  from the first case email ,so at the subject line for the second case , a prefix gets added as:RE .Now the system is not identifying it as a duplicate case and the case is open.

Do we have an option in code to get it identified with the  same subject line  (with prefix or without prefix )if the subject line matches duplicate case should get closed by adding its case comment to the first case which is open.

Any Suggestions

Here is a code :

```
trigger Case_DuplicateClose on Case (before insert) {
    Map<String, Case> newCaseMap = new Map<String, Case>();
    for(Case c : trigger.new)
    {
        if(newCaseMap.containsKey(c.Subject))
            c.Status = 'Closed';
        else
            newCaseMap.put(c.Subject, c);
    }
    for(Case c : [Select Subject From Case Where Subject in :newCaseMap.keySet()])
        newCaseMap.get(c.Subject).status = 'Closed';
}

trigger ReparentComment on CaseComment (before insert) {
    Map<String, Case> newCaseMap = new Map<String, Case>();
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, List<CaseComment>> ccMap = new Map<Id, List<CaseComment>>();
    for(CaseComment cc : trigger.new)
    {
        caseIds.add(cc.ParentId);
        List<CaseComment> ccList = ccMap.get(cc.ParentId);
        if(ccList == null)
            ccList = new List<CaseComment>();
        ccList.add(cc);
        ccMap.put(cc.ParentId, ccList);
    }
    for(Case c : [Select Id, Subject From Case Where Id in :caseIds Order by CreatedDate])
        if(newCaseMap.containsKey(c.Subject))
            for(CaseComment cc : ccMap.get(c.Id))
                cc.ParentId = newCaseMap.get(c.Subject).Id;
        else
            newCaseMap.put(c.Subject, c);

    for(Case c : [Select Id, Subject From Case Where Subject in :newCaseMap.keySet() And Id not in :caseIds And Status != 'Closed'])
        for(CaseComment cc : ccMap.get(newCaseMap.get(c.Subject).Id))
            cc.ParentId = c.Id;
}
```